# Issue with using wildcard parameter twice in a case class

Tags: scala, wildcard, case-class, existential-type

As peers the example below, I am trying to make a `case class` that can hold items of type `SomeResult[T]` without having to know what T is. This works fine in the case of `Rawr`, which can hold a `Set` of `SomeResult[_]`, however when I add a second field to try and work with on the same principle (i.e. a single element who's content we don't care about, and a set of elements), I get the following error

```
[error] /Users/matthewdedetrich/temp/src/main/scala/Main.scala:15: type arguments [_$2] do not conform to class SomeResult's type parameter bounds [A <: T]
[error] case class Bleh(oneThing:SomeResult[_],moreThings:Set[SomeResult[_]]) // This doesn't
```

Here is the sample code

```
trait T {

}

case class First(int:Int) extends T
case class Second(int:Int) extends T


case class SomeResult[A <: T](name:String, t:A)

case class Rawr(multipleThings:Set[SomeResult[_]]) // This works

case class Bleh(oneThing:SomeResult[_],moreThings:Set[SomeResult[_]]) // This doesn't
```

There is a suggestion to use a `[+A <: T]` as a type bound instead of a wildcard, however the following code doesn't work when doing this

```
val t = Set(First(3),Second(5))

def someFunc[A <: T](thing:A) = {
    thing match {
      case First(_) => SomeResult("a",First(10))
      case Second(_) => SomeResult("b",Second(15))
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("rawr")
    }
  }

  val z = t.map{
    case x:First => someFunc(First(5))
    case y:Second => someFunc(Second(5))
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("rawr")
  }

  val z2 = Rawr(z)
```

Which then provides the error

```
[error]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[SomeResult[Product with Serializable with T]]
[error]  required: Set[SomeResult[T]]
[error] Note: SomeResult[Product with Serializable with T] <: SomeResult[T], but trait Set is invariant in type A.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: SomeResult[T]`. (SLS 3.2.10)
```

Which is why I used wildcard types in the first place. Funnily enough, if you try to provide a return type to sumFunc, you get the exact same problem (where the scala compiler error suggests that you should use Wildcard types)

EDIT 2:
I have actually managed to get the code to compile by doing this

```
  def someFunc[A <: T](thing:A):SomeResult[A] = {
    thing match {
      case First(_) => SomeResult("a",First(10)).asInstanceOf[SomeResult[A]]
      case Second(_) => SomeResult("b",Second(15)).asInstanceOf[SomeResult[A]]
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("rawr")
    }
  }

  def z[A <: T]:Set[SomeResult[A]] = t.map{
    case x:First => someFunc(First(5)).asInstanceOf[SomeResult[A]]
    case y:Second => someFunc(Second(5)).asInstanceOf[SomeResult[A]]
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("rawr")
  }
```

Im not sure if its "idiomatic" or "right", but its the only way to get the `Serializable with Product` out of the type signature. I have no idea why Scala infers this when the result type is clearly a subtype of T

Comment: Second code snippet seems to be missing something (`t` is from where?), or is it supposed to go into `SomeResult` (even after putting it there I didn't get same error)? I would definitely recommend explicitly specifying return type of `someFunc` and a type of `z`, you might get a better idea of what is wrong.

Comment: Updated the post, also explicitly specifying the return result of someFunc doesn't work

Comment: Updated answer (gist: replacing A -> T in return types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't just use `T` instead of `_`?:

```
case class Bleh(oneThing:SomeResult[T],moreThings:Set[SomeResult[T]]) // Compiles
```

Then e.g. `Bleh(SomeResult("", First(0)), Set())` works fine.

Naming a trait as `T` is a bit unfortunate, it's easily confused with type parameter.

Answer to EDIT2:
Slightly edited and working:

```
val t: Set[T] = Set(First(3), Second(5))

def someFunc[A <: T](thing: A): SomeResult[T] = {
  thing match {
    case First(_) => SomeResult("a", First(10))
    case Second(_) => SomeResult("b", Second(15))
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("rawr")
  }
}

def z[A <: T]: Set[SomeResult[T]] = t.map {
  case x: First => someFunc(First(5))
  case y: Second => someFunc(Second(5))
  case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("rawr")
}
```

You were forcing a type `A` to `Set`, but `Set` is invariant (compiler was unable to make a `Set[T]` when got `t` of type `First`/`Second` [old method signatures was with `A`]).

Comment: Because then you can't put in different subtypes of T in the same case class instance.

Comment: Same instance - what you mean by that (your case class is immutable)? Or you mean different subtypes of T in set? But that works: `Bleh(SomeResult("",First(0)), Set(SomeResult("",First(1)),SomeResult("",Second(2))))`

Comment: The following code doesn't work with that signature

  `val someResult1 = SomeResult("s",First(4));
  val someResult2 = SomeResult("s",Second(5));

  val c = Rawr(Set(someResult1,someResult2))`

Comment: That's a variance issue of `SomeResult`, try `case class SomeResult[+A <: T](name:String, t:A)` (without it compiler can't convert `SomeResult[First]` to `SomeResult[T]` so it cannot create `Seq[SomeResult[T]]`).

Comment: Check the edit, I can't make my code work in a certain situation when using type bounds

Answer (score 1):

just to avoid confusion, these examples don't actually require existentials.  Replacing T with trout to avoid confusion, as the foobarbazzing of First Second SomeResult was bad enough for my tiny brain.

```
sealed trait trout {}

case class First(int:Int) extends trout
case class Second(int:Int) extends trout


case class SomeResult[A >: trout](name:String, t:A)

case class Rawr(multipleThings:Set[SomeResult[_]])

case class Bleh[T >: trout](oneThing:SomeResult[T],moreThings:Set[SomeResult[_]])

val von = SomeResult("Kilgore", First(99))
val ro = SomeResult("Mishka", Second(33))
val mika = SomeResult("Rivold", First(52))

// want this:
val troutses = List(von, ro, mika)


val result1 = troutses.map {
    case SomeResult(_, First(_)) => SomeResult("a", First(10))
    case SomeResult(_, Second(_)) => SomeResult("b", Second(15))
  }

// but this version:
def someFunc[A >: trout](thing: A): SomeResult[_] = {
  thing match {
    case First(_) => SomeResult("a", First(10))
    case Second(_) => SomeResult("b", Second(15))
  }
}
val indexSet = Set(First(3), Second(5))

val z = indexSet.map {
  case First(_) => someFunc(First(5))
  case Second(_) => someFunc(Second(5))
}

val z2 = Rawr(z)
```

All of this works fine.

-- TurdCollector